# How can I stretch EditText views in Android?

Tags: android, layout

This is my layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="One"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>    
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Two"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:inputType="numberSigned"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The problem, however, is that EditText views are ridiculously small - as small as possible I reckon. Is there a way to make them as wide as possible?

Answer (score 3):

make the second column of your tablelayout stretchable:

```
android:stretchColumns="1"
```

Hope this works

Comment: Worked! Thanks a bunch! Too bad I can't accept this because I accidentally posted with a new cookie-based account in Chrome's incognito mode :( Can an admin mark this this question as accepted please?

Comment: @forneo: You should rather try and ask an admin to attribute the question to you.

Answer (score 0):

Make their width fill_parent

```
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:inputType="numberSigned"/>
```

Comment: And giving it a static width e.g. 50dip?